# Find keyword matches, but ignore based on word proximity in ReGex JS

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to find matches for a word in a long string, however I want to set up a proximity around the first match, so that any words that match within the proximity get ignored.

For example, if I had an example string, where I'm looking for `test`:

```
Lorem ipsum Test sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Vestibulum at erat ac enim malesuada pulvinar et nec ante. 
Cras erat ipsum, pellentesque vel volutpat ut, Test eu test. 
Test Quisque tincidunt varius mi.
```

And this example uses a proximity of `15 words`, my end result would show these highlighted:

```
Lorem ipsum **Test** sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Vestibulum at erat ac enim malesuada pulvinar et nec ante. 
Cras erat ipsum, pellentesque vel volutpat ut, **Test** eu test. 
Test Quisque tincidunt varius mi.
```

So it only finds the `Test` that is first && greater than 15 words away.

---

So far I have tried something similar to this:

`\btest\W+(?:\w+\W+){15,}?test\b`

But this seems to highlight all the words between, when I really only want to highlight `test`. It also requires me to set 2 params of keywords, which I'd like to only have to use the `test` keyword once if possible.

Any ideas on how I could accomplish this sort of proximity behavior?

---

Clarification update:

I have an example on regex tester here: https://regex101.com/r/FDOWZU/1
You can see that it selects the entire amount of words between instances of `test`.
[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFCbb.png)

However, what I want is something more like this:
[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/in4bX.png)

Comment: It is a little bite unclear for me, could you please propose an example of your expected output with multiple study cases. Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi, sorry if that's unclear, I'll update the question for clarification

Comment: Ho sorry it's me. No worries.

Comment: Updated with a link to my regex tester link, and 2 images showing my current output, vs what I am trying to accomplish. hopefully that make sense!

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Let me know if the answer help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you mean `>=15` or `>15` since your code and written logic contradict each other. In any case, you can replace `14` with the number of words sought after. The upper hand `14` in this case ensures `test` isn't one of the next 15 words, so it will match `test` only if the next 15 words are not `test`.

---

You can use the following regex:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/FDOWZU/2)

```
\btest(?!\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,14}test)
```

```js
s = `Lorem ipsum Test sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum at erat ac enim malesuada pulvinar et nec ante. Cras erat ipsum, pellentesque vel volutpat ut, Test eu test. Test Quisque tincidunt varius mi. Suspendisse vitae lobortis diam. Vestibulum posuere massa id lectus faucibus posuere. Donec non sollicitudin est. Donec libero turpis, malesuada in Test`
r = /\btest(?!\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,14}test)/gi
var m
while(m = r.exec(s)) {
  console.log(m)
}
```

How it works:

- `\b` Word boundary
- `test` match this literally (case-insensitive with `i` flag)
- `(?!\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,14}test)` negative lookahead ensuring the following does not match:

  - `\W+` match any non-word character one or more times
  - `(?:\w+\W+){0,14}` match between zero and fourteen words
  - `test` match this literally (case-insensitive again)

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! This is definitely closer, when I mentioned it I was looking for basically wanting >= 15 words in between matches. I'm not 100% sure I'm following your quantifier of `{0,14}` because would that be saying "between 0 to 14"?  Also, theres a slight weird thing, where if I put another test next to an existing match. The first one un matches and it grabs the new one. I'm assuming this has to do with that quantifier?

Comment: @Fugazi I clarified it with a note. And yes, that's correct since there's no `test` after the second `test`. Should it be before and after?

Comment: @Fugazi if it's supposed to be before and after, you should use groups, although `(?<!test\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,14})test(?!\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,14}test)` will work in most modern browsers. Older browser versions (before V8) don't support lookbehinds, less even variable length lookbehinds.

Comment: Ah I see, yeah I think the better way i could have explained it is I basically want a 15+-word boundary between matches so it could be similar to: `test(matched) .... [ 22 word ] .... test(matched) .... [13 words] ... test (unmatched)`. My fault, I wasn't really sure how to explain this

Comment: @Fugazi you can use `(?:test\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,14})test|(test)(?!\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,14}test)` ensuring capture group 1 has a value - this will work with older browsers. If you don't care about older browser or non-V8 browser support, use the variable length lookbehind I proposed in my previous comment.

Comment: I'm running it off of a node script, so browsers aren't a specific worry of mine.

Comment: @Fugazi then you should be able to use the variable length lookbehind. Once you confirm the pattern that works for you, I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [working regex](https://regex101.com/r/CfYrnR/1): `(?<!test(?:\w|\s)*\W{0,14})test`

Here is how it works in the parenthesis:

- `?<!` is the negative lookbehind notation
- `test` look for the `test` words
- `(?:\w|\s)*` that are followed by any number of non word or space characters
- `\W{0,14}` then followed by 0 to 14 words

So all together it gives: Find all the `test` words that are **not** following a `test` word followed by at most 15 words.

Comment: Oh this is looking like exactly what I need, but if I wanted that last statement to be "Find all the test words that are not following a test word followed by **ATLEAST** 15 words or more." Would I need `\W{15,0}`? because that doesn't seem to give me my expected results

Comment: `not following a test word followed by at most 15 words` is equivalent to `greater than 15 words away` ;)

Comment: Have you tested the regex on other examples?

Comment: Lookbehind is not supported in alll browsers. And variable length lookbehind is not supported in most of languages.

Comment: He's using javascript so in this case it seems appropriate. Moreover he may be using node.